# How to manipulate HTML based on external XML source?

Tags: javascript, xml

Currently working on a digital signage campaign that I only want to be displayed when traffic slows down an x% on certain roads. I'm trying to use the open data from NDW and extract .XML data on the average speed that traffic is passing by the measuring location.

The data is provided through an external .XML file that is updated each minute. 
(http://opendata.ndw.nu/trafficspeed.xml.gz). The file is quite big so i'm looking for a sollution that extract the required data without having to handle a big file. (is this even possible?)

This is the code I've come up with so far. Could anyone give me some pointers or directions for me to look at and/or read about? Or if someone can show me how they would go about doing such a thing?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Verkeersinfo_test</title>
 <style>
 div {
 background-color: #d70080;
 }
 </style>
<script type="text/javascript">

let getXMLFile = function(path, callback){
 let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open("GET", path);
 request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
 request.onReadystatechange = function(){
  if (request.readyState ===4 && request.status === 200){
   callback(request.responseXML);
  }
 };
 request.send();
};

getXMLFile("http://opendata.ndw.nu/trafficspeed.xml.gz", function(xml){
 console.log(xml);
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *Extract* **means** *Reading* so... unfortunately

Comment: You might be able to make your life a bit easier by running the XML through an XSL template to have it only give you the parts that you care about.